# How can I pass an XML fragment as parameter when calling a module?

Tags: python, xml, microservices, fastapi

I am new to Python and am trying to setup a little microservice example with FastAPI.

The microservice setup is configured with a config XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
  <service name="Watch folder">
    <module name="folder_watcher">
      <port>8001</port>
      <folder>folder/to/watch</folder>
      <interval>5s</interval>
    </module>
  </service>
</config>
```

The main module reads like this (still work in progress):

```
import defusedxml.ElementTree
import subprocess
import pathlib
import os

SERVICE_DIR = 'service'

def launchService(service):
  print('Service: ' + service.attrib['name'])
  for module in service.findall('./module'):
    module_name = module.attrib['name']
    print('* Module: ' + module_name)
    parameters = module.findall('./*')
    for parameter in parameters:
      print('  * ' + parameter.tag + ': ' + parameter.text)
    folder_path = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve()
    command = os.path.join('python ', folder_path, SERVICE_DIR, module_name, 'main.py')
    print('* Command: ' + command)
    subprocess.Popen(command, parameters)

def loadConfig():
  # config.xml
  elementTree = defusedxml.ElementTree.parse('config.xml')
  for service in elementTree.findall('./service'):
    launchService(service)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  loadConfig()
```

And the folder_watcher module's main.py reads

```
import sys
from fastapi import FastAPI
import uvicorn

service = FastAPI()

@service.get("/")
async def root():
  return {"Message": "Hello World!"}

if __name__ == "__main__":
  parameters = sys.argv[1]
  for parameter in parameters:
      print('  * ' + parameter.tag + ': ' + parameter.text)
  uvicorn.run(service, host="localhost", port=8000)
```

A few questions arose during coding this:

- Is `subprocess.Popen` the right way to invoke the microservices?
- How can I provide the XML fragment for the configuration of the service as parameter?
- Are there other things, that I might have overseen?

Just to clarify a few things in advance: The example must be realized with FastAPI, I cannot make use of Docker / it must be realized "standalone pure Python" and it must make use of XML and not JSON or other structured text formats.

If this should be the wrong place for my question, please do not hesitate to point me into the right direction / the right board.

Comment: The command line is not a good way to pass something like an xml fragment and using a file would be better.

Comment: The example does not imply any command line interaction. I am calling a module from the main module and need to pass the XML fragment to the called module. Passing a file does also not help and iterating over the config file again is also no option.

Comment: The parameters `subprocess.Popen()` accepts are like using command line arguments. If the modules you're using are designed to be run programmatically, there should be some documentation of what they expect or accept to be passed just like the typically "usage" help one gets.

Comment: I see. Can I call the module's main.py and pass the XML fragment in another way? Are there best practices for passing complex data types as parameters to modules? Does ```uvicorn``` spawn its own subprocess, which could make ```subprocess.Popen()``` obsolete?

Comment: I don't know how `uvicorn` works. As fair as I know the best practice for passing complex arguments like this is via files as I said in my original comment. You could use the  `tempfile` module to create files for this purpose.